# error drupal after copy & paste folder, and same DB

Tags: drupal, admin

I just copied and pasted the whole drupal content folder from my server to my localhost and also I dumped the DB to my localhost, but now my admin user authentication credentials are not working in the localhost.

I even reset my admin password (`UPDATE admin SET pass = MD5('newpassword') WHERE uid=1;`)

Also in `watchdog` table I am having this message when I try to authenticate:

> "Session opened for %name."

Any ideas??

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your .htaccess file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was parameter `$cookie_domain` on file `/sites/default/settings.php`. it is working fine now